# OpenCL build failed, failed loading render kernel, isn't supported by clang

Tags: cycles-render-engine, linux, opencl

I have problem. I want to use GPU compute rendering, but when I change the userpreference cycles compute device to my gpu (OpenCL), blender cannot do rendering and shows that failed loading render kernel. 
[image]

This is the spec of my laptop GPU (not sure what is called):

```
farestp@farestp-X555QG:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD CARRIZO (DRM 3.18.0 / 4.13.0-36-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.1.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.1.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 18.1.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

[image]
I use Ubuntu 17.10. Asus-x555QG. Use oibaf's driver.

This is the appearance from console:

```
farestp@farestp-X555QG:~$ CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1 /home/farestp/Downloads/blender-2.79-b5b5260464f-linux-glibc219-x86_64/blender
Read prefs: /home/farestp/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /home/farestp/Downloads/blender-2.79-b5b5260464f-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python
trying to save userpref at /home/farestp/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend ok
trying to save userpref at /home/farestp/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend ok
trying to save userpref at /home/farestp/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend ok
Device init success
Compiling OpenCL program base
1 warning and 1 error generated.
OpenCL build failed with error CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE, errors in console.
OpenCL program base build output: Build option isn't yet supported by clang: -cl-no-signed-zeros
```

Is this bug? or I am missing something when install OpenCL? I am newbie with linux... :)

Thank you~

Comment: Remove pocl package and don't forget to install package from synaptic related to opencl fix this problem... But I encounter another problem... Maybe another people could solve more clear